# Pass Error Messages When Using form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

How can you pass an error messages coming from a model --> controller to view?

```
= form_tag :controller => "article", :action => "create" do
  / how to retrieve error messages here?
  %p
    = label_tag :article, "Article"
    = text_field_tag :article
  = submit_tag "Submit Article"
```

I have this model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :article

  validates         :article,      :presence => true
end
```

In my controller:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])

  if ! @article.save
    # how to set errors messages?
  end
end
```

I'm using Rails 3.0.9

Comment: Have you seen this? I believe it answers your question: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=30889 Also, why are you using `form_tag` using `form_for` should work better in this case right?

Comment: My plan here actually is to use another controller.

Comment: What you mean with "use another controller"? please provide more details from what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think he means that he wants to use a controller that accepts parameters for a nested resource? Anyway using `form_for` can even be used in a generic way like so: `form_for :article`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors messages are stored in your model. You can access through the errors methods, like you can see in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html.
 An easy way to expose the error message is including the follow line in your view:

```
%span= @article.errors[:article].first
```

But, I belive you have to change your controller to be like that:

```
def new
  @article = Artile.new
end

def create
  @article = Artile.new params[:article]
  if !@article.save
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

In the new action you don't need to try save the article, because the creation action already do that job. The new action exists, (basically) to call the new view and to provide support for validations messages.

Answer (score 0):

The `new`method shouldn't save anything. `create` method should.

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])

  if ! @article.save
    redirect_to root_path, :error => "ops! something went wrong.."
  end
end
```